# Arc length of a polar curve in terms of theta

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Is there an equation for such? I know that there is an equation for such in terms of r, but I must calculate the length of $tan(\theta) = 3/5$ (cartesian equivalent: $y = 3/5x$) from r = 0 to 1.457.

Comment: But if $\theta=0$ then $\tan\theta\ne\frac35$...

Comment: I made an error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This curve is a line. Draw it, and label both endpoints. How long is it? (No calculus is required).

Comment: Nvm, not even that I just realized the stupidity of my mistake and the fact that the arc length itself is just 1.457. Lol thanks though